# Teams Meeting showed in main windows instead of another windows

Tags: microsoft-teams

On my old laptop, Teams meeting showed in a separated windows. then I could chat with other colleagues while attending a meeting. (I'm using laptop with an external monitor)

On my new laptop, Teams meeting showed in a unified windows, or a small on-top windows, therefore it's hard for me to chat with other colleagues and use other Teams features while attending a meeting.
I've check and the configuration in `... / Settings` is similiar between 2 laptops
I've tried re-install Teams on new laptop but the issue still there.

How could I make Teams meeting windows work as before ?

[image: Teams on old laptop]

[image: Team on new laptop]
[image: Teams on new laptop]

Comment: Have you tried the 6 dots icon, the window appears to be docked, you can also try deleting the Teams data folder within AppData

Comment: This looks like the old meeting experience, from before separate windows. Did you compare the versions yet?

Comment: @DanielB I've checked version, it say `You have Microsoft Teams Version 1.5.00.9163 (64-bit). It was last updated on 5/6/22.`

Comment: @Ramhound I've Uninstall teams and deleted `Teams` folder in `%appdata%` but it doesn't help